# What is the latest version of R studio that can run on Windows 8.1?

Tags: r, rstudio

What is the latest version of R studio that can run on Windows 8.1?

Which version of R studio can I use to get all the required functionality on Windows 8.1 operating system?

Comment: Perhaps the Rstudio FAQ helps: https://www.rstudio.com/about/platform-support/

Comment: For RStudio support questions, try using their question site: https://community.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

The following version works for Windows 8.1 : 2023.03.2-454.pro2 "Cherry Blossom" (released on June 12, 2023).